# min-height is not changing for all pages of site

Tags: wordpress-theming, css

I used the css custom manager to change the min-height for my `WordPress` site.  The site has way too much blank space at the bottom.
When I changed the min-height it is only applied to the `home page`.
How do I get it to change for the rest of the pages?
I was told that I would have to make a child theme in order to get the manager to apply it to all pages.
Doing so is not possible for me.Is there any other suggestions?
[campwhiskers](http://www.campwhiskers.com) is the site (somehow the blog page is okay too?)

This is what I put into the manager to get the page to change:

```
#main .content, #main .last-content
{ 
    min-height:auto;
    padding-top:50px;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}
#main .last-content 
{ 
   min-height:auto!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your height on the other pages is being controlled by this property, which is on line 117 of your CSS:

```
    #main .content, #main .last-content {
        min-height: 1700px;
        padding-top: 50px;
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
}
```

There is another instance of this on line 59, which is where the confusion is.

Just delete this part of the CSS on line 177:

```
min-height: 1700px;
```

Here's a visual

[image]

Here is another screenshot. This one shows the css files your theme is using. You need to track down this file on your Bluehost server and delete the min-height part. I can't tell you how to find it though b/c I can't see your server. It's likely in the themes folder. If you paid for this theme, you can maybe get the author to guide you (or not). I think if you dig around, you'll find it though.

[image]

Comment: Your lines are different than mine.  Like 117 is where min-height is on mine.  Like 59 is:ul, ol{ margin-left:20px; } for me.  I have changed the min-height:1700px; to say auto instead of 1700 which fixed it for the home page.  You are saying to just delete the whole thing?

Comment: I deleted the min-height: 1700px; and it just set the home page back to having all the extra space at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, our line numbers may be different. I'm looking at it in Chrome (right click --> inspect element) and thats where i'm getting that line number from. Your interface may have it numbered differently. The min-height: 1700; is definitely the culprit thought so run a search on your CSS and delete it.

Comment: I still don't understand what your suggestion is (I am not very literate in this stuff).  When I delete that line is just puts the page back to having a huge space.  I changed the 1700 to say auto and it fixed it but just for the home page.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yea I did and it did not fix it.  Check the site now, the home page is back to having all the extra space.

Comment: Well I did it in firebug and it shows it fixing the problem, the problem is that firebug does not let you save anything so that is why I use the css custom manager and when I delete it in there, it does not work.  Any ideas?  Thank you by the way so far.

Comment: The CSS custom manager is likely a feature that is part of the theme you have from Wordpress. I can't see it to give you a good answer, but if you can search through it and update that line, it would solve your issue.

Comment: Or, if it gives you the ability to write your own CSS, you could add #main .content{ min-height: none;} and see if that takes care of it. I'm not sure where that rule would fall in your cascade though, so 50/50 shot.

Comment: The manager does allow you to overwrite the css and like I said, I changed the 1700px to auto and it fixed it for the home page only.  What is the point of css inspectors if you can't save the changes?!  I was able to find the problem and fix it in the manager but it does not fix all pages but in firebug, I can see the changes but can't save anything!  So frustrating.

Comment: yes, the firebug is merely a tool to see how the browser is interpreting your css, but it ultimately needs to be changed on the server css file. The absolute best way to solve this is to find where on your server the CSS file is and update it directly, not through the WP theme interface, but that me be too advanced.

Comment: write this and tell me what happens: #main .content, #main .last-content{
min-height: none;
}

Comment: The css file in bluehost is where I found it.  I changed it and uploaded the new file to bluehost and it did not change anything on the site.  That is when I was told I had to use the css manager to put the new css in, when I did that it just changed the home page.  This is what I followed to find it in my bluehost file manager:public_html/wp-content/themes/viewFullSite/css/default     I changed the # to auto and it did nothing for the site but it is saved correctly in the bluehost server

Comment: So, when you open that css file from your bluehost server, you should be able to do a search for "min-height" with whatever program you're using to view the CSS in (notepad++, coda, ect.). You should be able to locate it that way. I'm not familiar with the css manager that your theme has built into it or how it's set up to override the files, but I think it's just making it more difficult to understand how css works. I won't be able to help you directly because of the abstraction that the "css manager" is putting in there. But I know the solution is to overwrite or delete min-height: 1700;

Comment: So, my best advice is to 1- Open the CSS files that your theme uses on the server(it could be several files) 2- Open them with a text editor (like notepad++ or Sublime text) 3- Do a search for "min-height" and delete or override them to "none" when you find them.

Comment: That is what I did.  There must be another file with a min-height then but I don't know.  When I look at it through firebug it shows the exact same location in the css/default file.  How come when I save the changes and upload the new file to my server it does not change anything on the site?

Comment: I think you have the right idea: "There must be another file with a min-height then but I don't know." I agree and think that the theme you are using is using multiple css files, which is why you can't seem to get rid of it even when you think it's gone. You have to search through the themes/ files on your server and look for anything that ends in .css, then do a search on each of those for min-height in that file until you squash them all. I'm sorry you're having so much trouble with this theme. It's kind of the wild west out there for WP themes. If you purchased it, maybe the author can help

Comment: I updated with another screenshot above. I think you'll be able to dig around the server and find it, then it's just a simple delete.

Comment: Ok, I found several more and changed them, updated the file in bluehost but still nothing shows up on the site. That was a problem before and why I had to use a css manager plug in.  How do I get the changes I made in the server show?

Comment: Sorry, Kelly, but I can't help you any further because I can't see the server and see your files, or how you're attempting to save them. Try watching this screencast to get a better feel for how WP works and the file structure. It may not answer your question exactly, but It'll make you more familiar with WP. http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/41-wordpress-as-a-cms/    If you can't get it on your own, then you may need to hire a developer to get in there and take care of it for you. Or ask whoever sold you the theme. I think you'll be able to get it yourself eventually though. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "much blank space at the bottom", the copyright section then

In style.css, at line 122 - copyright {
margin-bottom: 70px;

modify margin-bottom: 
to  lower value like 10px;

Comment: That did nothing.  I am talking about all the space above the copyright line.

Comment: hmm.. well I can minimize the copyright part size for your page by changing .copyright{margin-bottom:10px;

Comment: however, to modify what you need is -div.one-half, div.one-third, div.two-third, div.three-fourth, div.one-fourth in style.css. Change margin-bottom: 0em   line 109-112 in style.css